# Java memory dump issue

Tags: memory-leaks, java-5

I have tried to create a memory dump using with below code

```
 **/usr/lib/jvm/j2sdk1.5-sun/bin/jmap -heap 10699**
```

but i got below mentioned error, anyone can help to me

**Attaching to process ID 10699, please wait...
Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process**

I'm using java 5

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

To be proactive, I'll assume you're running ubuntu.  In that case, type the following:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

If you're not running ubuntu, I'll recommend that you run jmap as the same user as ran your target process

Comment: Probably worth linking to [bug JDK-7050524](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7050524) which documents this.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you're on ubuntu)

A quick fix is `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`.

If you want this to survive a reboot, and you don't want to compromise the protection that a restricted `ptrace_scope` provides, I recommend using `setcap cap_sys_ptrace=eip` on the binaries that require ptrace. For a java developer, you can run this command (as root)

```
find /usr/lib/jvm -type f -perm -o+x -exec setcap cap_sys_ptrace=eip {} \;
```